# SSH connection hangs with packet loss

Tags: ssh

I am trying to connect to a server at work using ssh after having established an `openvpn` connection.

This worked perfectly for months up till yesterday. Since of today the `ssh user@server` just hangs.

A verbose output gives me

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to *** [***] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
```

And then nothing happens....

Nothing changed in the configuration. I actually succesfully connected just the other day.

I also pinged the server to be sure he was not down. And there I noticed I get a huge packet loss (order 70%)

Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is not the SSH server/client connection but the connection itself. **If you are seeing a huge packet loss you should check**:

1. The physical cables, routers, switches, etc. Change everything. If the packet loss is only when you ping the server, then check the server physical installation
2. Check the server workload, maybe is hanged. Restart the server if necessary.

Comment: thx but as I said, the server is at work and I am 100 miles away from it...

Comment: @MathiasVanwolleghem I already told you the steps to find out the problem locally (**IF** the problems are local) otherwise is your work server failing so you may need to give a call to the IT department.

Comment: update: back at work and learned that a network card broke down over the weekend here. Most machines at the offices were hardly reachable. Explains the high packet loss that I was only experiencing when pinging servers at my work site...

Comment: Then, it answered your question ;).

Answer (score 2):

In case the connection issues aren't on your side and you need to get some work done, `mosh` ([man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/mosh.1.html), [home page](http://mosh.mit.edu/)) handles flaky connections way better than plain SSH can. Once installed on both machines, you can use it just like `ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, while better than total hanging of ssh connections, `mosh` was not a usable solution in high-packet-loss situation. Not to mention that you need to have privileges to modify the server, firewalls, etc. to use it.

So I wrote ssh wrapper called [ssh-line-mode](https://github.com/mnalis/ssh-line-mode) (as it does what `telnet(1)` line mode did back in the days) - eg. which provides you with local line editor (so you can edit, recall history, etc. whole line and edit it without any lag locally, and it only gets sent to server via standard `ssh` once you press enter, where lag is much more tolerable).

It works wonders in both high packet-loss and high latency situations, but it isn't magic - if you are out of the shell and need full screen remote access (eg. `ncurses` application at remote side) you'll have to press a hotkey to disable line mode and use standard character-by-character `ssh` mode until you want to return to fast line mode.